# Are monero addresses always 95 characters long?

Tags: address

Is a monero address always 95 characters long? Reason why is i generated a 93 character somehow from one of my apps im building out. I'm sure its just a bug on my part, but as this only happened once for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because Monero uses a modified base58 encoding method. During encoding, it breaks the address into 8 byte blocks and adds padding in order to guarantee that the resulting base58 address is always 95 characters long.